# Meteor: mongo exit code 48

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

It is, for me, impossible to start Meteor on ONE specific computer we have. On all the others, it's fine. It's running

```
Linux ip-10-2-103-74 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and `Meteor 1.0.4.1`

Nothing is running on the ports I use. The ports are open and available. I use a different port every time (random) to rule out any zombie stuff claming these ports. I have chmod'ed everything to 777 (and also tried running with sudo) to rule out any permission issues.

Attempt 1:

```
$ meteor create fresh_project
$ cd fresh_project
$ meteor --port 3863

fresh_project: created.                       

To run your new app:                          
  cd fresh_project                            
  meteor                                      
[[[[[ ~/tests/fresh_project ]]]]]             

=> Started proxy.                             
Unexpected mongo exit code 48. Restarting.    
Unexpected mongo exit code 48. Restarting.    
Unexpected mongo exit code 48. Restarting.    
Can't start Mongo server.                     
MongoDB exited because its port was closed, or was already
taken by a previous instance of MongoDB

Check for other processes listening on port 3863
or other Meteor instances running in the same project.
```

The stand-alone mongodb, by the way, complains about a lot of stuff

```
$ tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
Thu Mar 19 14:01:25.257 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Mar 19 14:01:25.257 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Mar 19 14:01:25.257 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Mar 19 14:01:25.259 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket: 127.0.0.1:28017
Thu Mar 19 14:01:25.264 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Mar 19 14:01:25.264 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Mar 19 14:01:25.264 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Thu Mar 19 14:01:25.264 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Thu Mar 19 14:01:25.281 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Mar 19 14:01:25.281 dbexit: really exiting now
```

changing the port there does not help either. Killing it entirely and 
removing mongodb with purge, reinstalling meteor, creating a fresh project, none of that does the trick. I have probably tried every step in every bug report I could find.

Attempt 2:

```
~/myapp$ MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp meteor run --port 4243
$ ./run.sh 
[[[[[ ~/myapp ]]]]]                           

=> Started proxy.                             
W20150319-16:03:52.596(1)? (STDERR) Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
W20150319-16:03:52.607(1)? (STDERR)     at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
W20150319-16:03:52.608(1)? (STDERR)     at Server._listen2 (net.js:1024:19)
W20150319-16:03:52.608(1)? (STDERR)     at listen (net.js:1065:10)
W20150319-16:03:52.608(1)? (STDERR)     at net.js:1147:9
W20150319-16:03:52.608(1)? (STDERR)     at dns.js:72:18
W20150319-16:03:52.608(1)? (STDERR)     at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:4243/
```

However, the app is inaccessible both from the computer itself, and naturally also from the outside world.

Comment: I know this is old, but since I have a similar error, I thought I'd ask if you found a solution. It does appear that your mongodb.log asks if anything on 127.0.0.1:28017, so maybe that was the issue? Thanks.

Comment: @ChipCastle answer posted. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the loopback interface was not up. So no ports could be bound at all.